# iOS 8 crashes in UVManager.m which is not one of my classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, crashlytics, appsee

I am seeing quite a few crash reports in `Crashlytics` for one of my apps.
All crashes have occurred in iOS 8, non jailbroken on both iPad and iPhone.

The crash report points to a class called `UVManager.m` however I cannot find a class with this name in my code at all.
So it is either included in an attached library that I use, or part of the iOS 8 frameworks.

How can I find out where the problem lies or what framework is causing the problem?

The crash is:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
```

Here's the crash log:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001974efbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018b7af654 -[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:] + 244
2  UIKit                          0x000000018b70e9f4 +[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:] + 260
3  UIKit                          0x000000018b81dbc0 __79-[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]_block_invoke + 148
4  UIKit                          0x000000018b6b5660 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 508
5  UIKit                          0x000000018b7fcf24 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 64
6  UIKit                          0x000000018b737fdc -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 464
7  UIKit                          0x000000018b710148 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1008
8  UIKit                          0x000000018b70fd38 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 528
9  UIKit                          0x000000018b6b52f4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
10 UIKit                          0x000000018b6b52f4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
11 UIKit                          0x000000018b69e44c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
12 UIKit                          0x000000018b6b4c90 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
13 UIKit                          0x000000018b6b491c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
14 UIKit                          0x000000018b6ade70 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
15 UIKit                          0x000000018b681660 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
16 CelebBooth-1D                  0x00000001001742a0 uvSendEvents (UVManager.m:138)
17 UIKit                          0x000000018b91fd6c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992
18 UIKit                          0x000000018b67fbc8 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
19 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186eb6324 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
20 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186eb55c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
21 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186eb3678 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
22 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186de1664 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
23 GraphicsServices               0x000000018ff235a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
24 UIKit                          0x000000018b6e6984 UIApplicationMain + 1488
25 CelebBooth-1D                  0x00000001000c23c4 main (main.m:16)
26 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000197b4aa08 start + 4
```

Comment: https://github.com/cmercier/UTProfiler/blob/master/uvmanager.h ?

Comment: Nope, definitely not that

Comment: Does your App allow extensions of some kind? Or sharing? The crash log suggest the crash occurred in the Framework `CelebBooth`, which is also an iOS application (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/celeb-booth-create-free-fun/id713998181?mt=8). Your might open this app in some way, and the app crashes but Crashlytics sends you the crash log anyway.

Comment: That is the app that is crashing, but I have no UVManager class.

Comment: Actually not the one you linked to, but similar

Comment: Does your app somewhat link to that app?

Comment: CelebBooth is my app (just a different one that you linked to above).

Comment: So main.m is my app start point, but UVManager isn't in my code. It must be in a linked library, but how do I find out where or which one?

Comment: Do you use any Frameworks? A good place to start is to go into your project directory and search for it: `grep -r "UVManager" .`

Comment: Or search for the file: `find . -iname 'UVManager*'`

Comment: Ok thanks. grep did in fact result with a framework I was using. I guess I can't actually get into the framework build to take a look at it?

Comment: Depends on what Framework it is. Most, however, are closed source, but if you're lucky you can find the source code on Github.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks

Comment: If you found what framework it is then I suggest filing a bug report with the dev. Also, take a look at custom keys in Crashlytics, it might point you towards what's causing the issue: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92520-how-do-i-use-custom-keys

Comment: I have notified the dev. Custom keys looks great, i must have missed them. Thanks

Comment: What frameworks do you use? List your pods

Comment: It was SuperSonicAds framework

Answer (score 3):

Are you using [AppSee](https://www.appsee.com/)? I believe the `UVManager` is part of their SDK

Comment: Correct.  Here's a snippet from the AppSee support documentation: 

"Appsee intercepts and logs and every touch gesture that is occurring within the app, and then dispatches it back to the original implementation. The UVManager class, is the class that is responsible for this behavior.

Therefore, this class may often come up in crashed sessions stack traces, but it is not the crash's root cause." [Source](http://support.appsee.com/customer/portal/articles/1881032-why-do-i-see-appsee-uvmanager-in-my-crash-call-stack-)